# What pattern could I use to set a filetype for files ending in '.ot.txt'

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I'd like to use VimOutliner with files ending in `.ol.txt`. This entry in `~/.vim/ftdetect/votl.vim` doesn't do that

```
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.ol.txt   setfiletype votl
```

Is there a `[pattern]` for this?

Comment: remove the `!` and try it

Comment: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ol.txt   setfiletype votl` didn't work :(

Comment: See question linked by @Mass. Use `set filetype=votl` in your autocmd, instead of `setfiletype votl`. The former is stronger and will override the latter.